# Weird Moment-Timezone Behavior | UTC-LT Converstion

Tags: node.js, moment-timezone

I try to convert UTC Times to Local Times

I have this Script

```
var moment = require("moment-timezone");

var utcDateStart = moment.utc("2022-03-12").startOf("day");
var utcDateEnd = moment.utc("2022-03-12").endOf("day");


let ltDateStart = utcDateStart.clone().tz("Europe/Berlin").startOf("day").utc();
let ltDateEnd = utcDateEnd.clone().tz("Europe/Berlin").endOf("day").utc();


console.log(ltDateStart, ltDateEnd);
```

I get this result:

```
Moment<2022-03-11T23:00:00Z> Moment<2022-03-13T22:59:59Z>
```

But i expect  this:

```
Moment<2022-03-11T23:00:00Z> Moment<2022-03-12T22:59:59Z>
```

I dont get it... Is this a bug? How can i achieve this? (without subtracting 1 day)

Comment: Why `utc` -> `Europe/Berlin` -> `utc` ? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @0stone0 following problem:  i have an date "DD.MM.YYYY" and an Timezone e.g. "Europe/Berlin" now i need the beginning and the end of the day in UTC format